# How can I hide the labels of the countrys in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I am attempting to make a web game where you have to name as many countries as you can but first I need to hide the labels. Can this be done? If so how I have found nothing in the documentation relating to hiding labels.
Thanks in advance

```
import './style.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

Comment: The [`OSM`](https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/apidoc/module-ol_source_OSM-OSM.html) source provides access to OpenStreetMap tile server.  Those tiles contain the labels.  Use a different source of tiles that doesn't contain the labels.

Comment: I believe I have a custom tile that could be used (ttps://api.maptiler.com/tiles/countries/tiles.json?key=KEY)
How can this be implemented into ol

Comment: There are several examples of using maptiler tiles in openlayers in the documentation: https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/examples/?q=maptiler